# How can I get equal sized axes with R rgl 3D plots

Tags: r, rgl

I am plotting a 3D point plot with the rgl-package with

```
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), cex.lab=1)
plot3d(cart$x,cart$y,cart$z,"X","Y","Z")
```

This work so far. Only the 3 axis are differently sized due to the values.

I would need identical sizes axes.

Here is the current output.
All 3 axes should go to 10000, or whatever I set.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

(xlim etc does not work as I understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the challenge by adding three points at the end of the axes.

```
endpoints <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
       x  y z
       -11000  0   0
       0  -11000 0
       0  0 11000
       ")
cart <- rbind(cart, endpoints)
plot3d(cart$x,cart$y,cart$z,"X","Y","Z")
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `aspect3d(1,1,1)` (although no reproducible example was given)

From `?aspect3d`:

> `aspect3d(x, y = NULL, z = NULL)`
> If the ratios are all 1, the bounding box will be displayed as a
> cube approximately filling the display. Values may be set larger
> or smaller as desired.